# Instead of trigger , insert on view

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, triggers

I have this view

```
CREATE VIEW NaveTiconderoga AS
SELECT nume, tip, cate_arme, diametru_tun, deplasament, Nave.clasa, anul_lansarii
FROM Clase, Nave
WHERE Clase.clasa = Nave.Clasa AND Nave.Clasa = 'Ticonderoga';
```

I wish to create a trigger to allow inserting through this view.

I wrote the following code, but i'm sure that it isn't correct as far as the WHERE clause from the SELECT.
Any pointers please?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER ticonderoga
instead of insert on NaveTiconderoga
referencing new as new old as old
begin
insert into clase (clasa, tip, cate_arme, diametru_tun, deplasament)
values (:new.clasa, :new.tip, :new.cate_arme, :new.diametru_tun, :new.deplasament);

insert into nave (nume, clasa, anul_lansarii)
values (:new.nume, :new.clasa, :new.anul_lansarii);
end;
```

Comment: What "isn't correct"?  You haven't posted your table definitions.  You haven't shown us an example of the `INSERT` statement you're using.  You haven't told us what the trigger actually does.  You haven't told us how that differs from what you want the trigger to do.

Comment: Do you mean that it lets you insert a record into the view, which then doesn't appear in the view; because you can insert a `clasa` value that isn't `'Ticonderoga'`?

Comment: what i want to say is, how would i interpret this inside the trigger "WHERE Clase.clasa = Nave.Clasa AND Nave.Clasa = 'Ticonderoga';"

Comment: You're inserting the same `clasa` values in both tables, so not sure why that join would be an issue; the filter might though. I'm not sure what you mean by 'interpret' though - what do you want to happen if a different `clasa` value is used?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to restrict the value inserted into the view (and thus the underlying tables), so you can't put in something that the view itself won't show, you can't use a check constraint; but you can test the value inside the trigger and throw an exception if you see something you don't like:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER ticonderoga
instead of insert on NaveTiconderoga
referencing new as new old as old
begin
  if :new.clasa is null or :new.clasa != 'Ticonderoga' then
    raise_application_error(-20001, 'Invalid clasa');
  end if;

  insert into clase (clasa, tip, cate_arme, diametru_tun, deplasament)
...
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/9545b/2) of what I think you're worried about. If you change the trigger in that to:

```
create trigger tr42
instead of insert on v42
begin
if :new.id != 1 then
raise_application_error(-20001, 'Invalid ID');
end if;
insert into t42 (id) values (:new.id);
end;
/
```

... then the second insert will fail. I think that is what you want to happen, anyway.